# Как вычислить значение в строке, относительно предыдущей строки?

Tags: sql, postgresql

пример таблицы.
**id, месяц, количество товара**
и хочу добавить столбец- динамика то-есть это отношение нынешнего количества к предыдущему что б видеть, ч в предыдущем было количество 5, а сейчас 10- значит показатель должен быть 2
Как написать SQL в данном случае?

Comment: какое нить `qnt / lag(qnt, 1) over (order by id)` ?

Comment: @teran я группирую по датам(то-есть изначально строк очень много) и когда я пытаюсь сгруппировать просто по месяцам или дням- мне надо взять предыдущий, что б вычислить прирост или убыток. Но пишет, что если группируете, то функция lag не работает

Comment: ну дак вы пишите вопрос целиком, а не обрывочно. и вы всегда можете сделать подзапрос к результатам группировки, или CTE, или что там есть в postgresql

Comment: "_Но пишет, что если группируете, то функция lag не работает_" кто пишет ? и как вы пытаетесь ее применять ? обычно оконные функции работают _после_ группировки. только что проверил на postgress `lag(count(1)) over(order by x)` отлично дало результат count() из предыдущей строки. И да, в любом случае когда на текущем уровне что то не получается, можно его обернуть в следующий уровень и выполнить операцию там. Вот вчера давал трехэтажный ответ с lag: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737402/194569